# Class of optimization problems whose decision versions are in P

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np, complexity-classes

NPO is defined to be the class of optimization problems whose decision versions are in **NP**. 
I would like to get the complexity class of optimization problems whose decision versions are in **P**.

Is such a complexity class already defined?